# How to handle facebook/google/etc OAuth2 using django rest framework?

Tags: django, oauth-2.0, django-rest-framework

I have an application which use rest-framework for communication between client (javascript mvc) and server(django) and I want that this communication will be allowed only for logged users and my users will be able to register via my custom registration and also to login via google or facebook or anythong else.

I am able to complete OAuth2 flow and now I have access token from google/fb and profile info.

But I am really really confused what to do next, of course I can create user instance, but I dont now where to store access token, or if thats even necessary.

Whats recommended approach? Should I use access token for accessing my APIs like this?

```
 curl -H "Authorization: Bearer <your-access-token>" http://localhost:8000/api/...
```

or should I login new user, create new session for him, which then I send to client and use sessionAuthentication? Or anything completly else?

I cant find any example of doing this :(

I checked OAuth2 part of rest framework doc http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication#oauth2authentication but It looks like mentioned django-oauth2-provider is only for creating my own OAuth2 system.

Im sorry if it sounds like stupid question, but I really appreciate any advice.

Comment: This is duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24430484/django-rest-framework-oauth2-consumer-api-from-external-provider.