# Steps to generate OAuth2 token in hierarchical stage in Datastage

Tags: datastage, ibm-infosphere

How to generate OAuth2 token in hierarchical stage in Datastage job. What are the steps to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You do not generate the Oauth token in the stage itself. The Bearer Token or Refresh token is created and provided to you by the Authentication server you're connecting to. So ask the owner of the system you're connecting to to generate the Oauth token for you and you enter it into the "Bearer token" field in the hierarchical stage.

To save on me repeating info that's already in Stack Exchange, here is some extra reading on the token: [What is the OAuth 2.0 Bearer Token exactly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25838183/what-is-the-oauth-2-0-bearer-token-exactly)

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the Info. We need to generate the token(which will be valid for that call only) on every call from a Token URL, by providing client secret key and password, further need to grab that token in stage and then use it for Bearer token, will be great to have info on this.