# How to fetch data from an Authenticated API in React using Axios?

Tags: reactjs, axios

I have an authenticated API from that i want to fetch the data. I am doing this in REACT using Axios.. How to do this?

Comment: Most commonly this is done through the `Authorization` header

Comment: Could you please explain clearly i am new bie so..or else can you share the where i can get the clear idea of this??

Answer (score 1):

Something like below

```
const AuthString = 'Bearer '.concat(USER_TOKEN); 
axios.get(URL, { headers: { Authorization: AuthString } })
 .then(response => {
     console.log(response.data);
  })
 .catch((error) => {
     console.log('error ' + error);
  });
```

Comment: I found the Bearer ans User Token in Post man..What those things are actually?

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25838183/what-is-the-oauth-2-0-bearer-token-exactly/25843058

Answer (score 0):

1- You can create something like this if you already have access token.

```
const authAxios = axios.create({
baseURL: "yourURL",
headers: {
  Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
},
```

});

2- After creating the axios, you can use the created axios when hitting the API:

```
  authAxios.get("URL").then((res) => {
    return res.data;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).