# Detect all Cancelled Jobs in Ansible AWX / Tower

Tags: ansible, ansible-awx, ansible-tower

I am trying to detect all cancelled jobs in Ansible AWX / Tower by querying the API on a periodic basis. Trying to figure out how to do it. Here is what I have.

```yaml
- name: Pull Jobs Data
    uri:
      url: https://ansible2.xrxi.com/api/v2/jobs/?format=json&page=1&page_size=1000
      headers:
        Content-Type: application/json
        Authorization: "Bearer {{ lookup('env', 'TOWER_PASSWORD') }}"
    register: jobs_data

- name: Add jobs data to dictionary - Cancelled jobs
    set_fact:
      list_of_jobs_info: "{{ list_of_jobs_info + [{ 'job_id' : item['id'], 'job_name' : item['name'], 'job_status' : item['status'],  'job_cancel' : item['canceled_on'], 'job_template_id' : item['summary_fields']['job_template']['id'], 'job_template_name' : item['summary_fields']['job_template']['name'] }] }}"
    when:
    - item['canceled_on'] is defined
    - item['summary_fields']['job_template'] is defined
    - item['job_status'] == "Failed"
    loop: "{{ jobs_data['json']['results'] }}"

    register : subset_data

  - debug:
      var: subset_data
```

Currently it seems to be failing on `item['job_status'] == "Failed"`.

Comment: Just a note to make the code better maintainable. The variable name in `Authorization: "Bearer {{ lookup('env', 'TOWER_PASSWORD') }}"` should be `TOWER_TOKEN` since that is what it is, a [Bearer Token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25838183/).

Comment: if this answer good for you please accept it

Comment: Changing to 'TOWER_TOKEN' did not work. Not sure why.

Answer (score 1):

Try to switch

- from  `- item['job_status'] == "Failed"`
- to `- item['status'] == "Failed"`

since it's look like the `item['job_status']` is not defined.

Comment: Right, that's the case according [Tower API Reference Guide - Jobs - List Jobs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/latest/html/towerapi/api_ref.html#/Jobs/Jobs_jobs_list) "_**GET** `/api/v2/jobs/`
List Jobs_" and where results and job data structure fields are documented.