# Guide for bearer token validation by a Java web service using Oltu?

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, oltu

I'm adding a simple web service to an older application that needs to authenticate via OAuth 2.0. Since the app uses older technologies (Java 6, Tomcat 6, Struts 1, no Spring Framework) and upgrading the app is not currently in the scope, budget, or schedule for the project, I'm working with the Apache Oltu libraries -- older, but they appear to be adequate for my needs.

The service will be passed a bearer token from the consumer in the request headers, which I can retrieve. I believe next would be to pass the token with the web service's client id and secret from it's authorization OAuth account to an (as yet unknown to me) Oltu token validation routine that will use a PingFederate URL in our company's domain for validation (i.e., "https://fedlogin.xxx.com/as/token.oauth2"), and get back whether or not it's a valid token. This is a very low traffic web service, so I don't think I need to worry about refresh tokens, storing anything in keyvaults/caches/databases, etc.

What I'm looking for seems simple, but maybe I'm oversimplifying things in my understanding of the process. I've found lots of examples online but not a guide or example that lays out the correct method(s), parameters, etc. to validate the bearer token in *this* situation. I've unsuccessfully tried a number of different variations on examples I've found online. I'm new to OAuth so I may be having difficulty with the terminology and naming conventions for the available classes and methods.

Can anyone suggest (or guide me to) a method to quickly and simply validate the bearer token using Oltu?  Am I on the right track or am I missing/misunderstanding something fundamental in how OAuth 2 validation from a web service's perspective works?

**Edit:** I think I may have an answer for why I can't find a solution in the Oltu library -- it doesn't exist.  See my response below...

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have found an answer in a previous post to my question :

"This interaction between the RS and the AS is not part of the OAuth 2.0 standard ... and it's up to the AS implementation to decide how to accomplish this task." -- [How resource server in OAuth authentication system, verify the token?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37032501/7432797)

This is the part I was missing -- the implementation of the authentication method used by the resource server to validate the client's token against the authentication server is left up to the authorization server.  This means that it will likely not be included in many general-purpose OAuth 2.0 libraries such as Oltu (which is why I could not find one).  In my case, I'll need to find an older version of the PingFederate Java Integration Kit since our company uses a PingFederate server for authentication.