# Debugging The interface between Resource Server and Authorization Server (oauth 2.0. validation access token)

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, okta

There are two `spring-boot` apps.

1. `client`
2. `resource-sever`
   there is dev okta account that is used as `auth server`

(those 2 apps are standard `Spring Boot` client -> resource-server, almost out of the box with okta setup for them, should not be problem there)

`client` - securely sends messages to-->  `secure-sever` (passing the access token in the header as prove that it's authorized to call it and get data back)

(it works as expected)

But I am trying to figure out what's going on between all them, traffic wise

I'm trying to spot that moment when `resource-server` checks the `token` it got from the `client` that got it from the `auth server`.

Here is a sequence diagram of standard `oauth 2.0 flow` and that part that I want to debug (arrow)

`auth server`

[image]

And there is a communications between `client`, `resource-sever`:

[image]

There seems I can not confirm that Resource Server (from the right) does any **token validation** with the `auth-server` (okta)..?

**Question:** is why? From my understanding it is supposed to validate it (somehow).

I was expecting to see a call from resource-server to auth-server (otka) with the [token-validation-request](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7662) (ETF RFC 7662 in October 2015) like this:

[How to validate an OAuth 2.0 access token for a resource server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12296017/how-to-validate-an-oauth-2-0-access-token-for-a-resource-server/28048217#28048217)

I was expecting, lets say, tat for every client call, resource server would check if that token the client passes is valid. Yet I do not see any calls from resource service to okta that would use the token in its requests to okta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This comes down to the difference between JWTs and opaque tokens.

It looks like your application is using JWTs, based on the calls I'm seeing to `/keys`.

When using JWT authentication the resource server will query the `jwks_url` (in this case `/keys`) on startup to retrieve a set of public keys that it can use to validate the JWT-encoded bearer tokens.

Then, when the resource server receives a bearer token in a request from the client it will validate its signature against a public key obtained from the `jwks_url` endpoint.

This means the resource server doesn't have to query the authorization server on every request.
You can read more about this process in the [OAuth 2.0 Resource Server JWT](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/resource-server/jwt.html) section of the Spring Security reference documentation.

The question that you linked to refers to opaque tokens.
In this setup, the resource server must call the authorization server **introspection** endpoint to validate the token every time.
You can read more about this process in the [OAuth 2.0 Resource Server Opaque Token](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/resource-server/opaque-token.html) section of the Spring Security reference documentation.

Comment: It should be mentioned though, that this method can't validate if a token has been revoked after it had been issued

Comment: There's still periodic call to/keys   endpoint so if token is reinvoked, I guess it keep the keys up to date.  Not sure what happens in hr moment if New reinvoked tokens, I guess extra /keys call will be made..?