# Social Login using Google and Facebook in Flutter App

Tags: flutter, facebook, authentication, google-signin

I am trying to implement my own server authentication (email, password) along with Facebook, and Google login. I would like to list what I have searched. Facebook login only returns an access token while Google login returns an access token and an id token.

I am planning to create my own JWT token in the backend, so **which parameters (id token/access token) should be passed to my backend server to verify if the end user is logged in using Facebook or Google?** I have some confusion about whether the access token is being used for authorization instead of authentication.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to validate an OAuth 2.0 access token for a resource server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12296017/how-to-validate-an-oauth-2-0-access-token-for-a-resource-server)

Comment: No, should I use an id token or access token from Google/Facebook to implement my custom authentication? I can't differentiate the function between the id token and access token in terms of implementing authentication.

Answer (score 0):

The token you get from google and facebook contain user data eg email, profile image etc you need to decode them.

Assuming email is unique in your db then you can query if exists and generate tokens on success.

example on how to decode [google tokens](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth) in python

TLDR

```
from google.oauth2 import id_token
from google.auth.transport import requests

# (Receive token by HTTPS POST)
# ...

try:
    # Specify the CLIENT_ID of the app that accesses the backend:
    idinfo = id_token.verify_oauth2_token(token, requests.Request(), CLIENT_ID)

    # Or, if multiple clients access the backend server:
    # idinfo = id_token.verify_oauth2_token(token, requests.Request())
    # if idinfo['aud'] not in [CLIENT_ID_1, CLIENT_ID_2, CLIENT_ID_3]:
    #     raise ValueError('Could not verify audience.')

    # If auth request is from a G Suite domain:
    # if idinfo['hd'] != GSUITE_DOMAIN_NAME:
    #     raise ValueError('Wrong hosted domain.')

    # ID token is valid. Get the user's Google Account ID from the decoded token.
    userid = idinfo['sub']
except ValueError:
    # Invalid token
    pass
```

Response

```
{
 // These six fields are included in all Google ID Tokens.
 "iss": "https://accounts.google.com",
 "sub": "110169484474386276334",
 "azp": "1008719970978-hb24n2dstb40o45d4feuo2ukqmcc6381.apps.googleusercontent.com",
 "aud": "1008719970978-hb24n2dstb40o45d4feuo2ukqmcc6381.apps.googleusercontent.com",
 "iat": "1433978353",
 "exp": "1433981953",

 // These seven fields are only included when the user has granted the "profile" and
 // "email" OAuth scopes to the application.
 "email": "testuser@gmail.com",
 "email_verified": "true",
 "name" : "Test User",
 "picture": "https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-kYgzyAWpZzJ/ABCDEFGHI/AAAJKLMNOP/tIXL9Ir44LE/s99-c/photo.jpg",
 "given_name": "Test",
 "family_name": "User",
 "locale": "en"
}
```